# Apache rewrite a external URL, it´s possible?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The problem is this: when the user enters to a specific ip address i want the apache to redirect to another page but i want to maintain the same url in the explorer, any idea of how i can achieve the goal?

Comment: Read up on [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: Alejandro. Was the below answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

To simply redirect a request for a site's root to a specific resource, a common method is to use:

RewriteRule ^/$ /test/mypage.html

where /test/mypage.html represents the URI you want to display. If you need to conditionally execute the Rewrite based on the incoming hostname (IP), then you would either place the RewriteRule inside a VirtualHost for the desired IP or place a RewriteCond right above the RewriteRule. For example:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.1\.100$
RewriteRule ^/$ /test/mypage.html

where 192.168.1.100 is the specific IP address you want to redirect from.

Comment: Alejandro. Did this answer help? Thanks